# Count matching values between different columns of grouped rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

This particular dataset consists of 3 households and its members. Columns 3 and 4 indicate if that member lives with their parents. Its value is the identity of mother and father in the Member column. For example member 3 lives with mother (2) and father (1).

```
Household  Member  Lives_with_m  Lives_with_f  New_col
    1        1         NaN          NaN          1
    1        2         NaN          NaN          1
    1        3          2            1           1
    1        4         NaN          NaN          1    
    1        5          3            4          NaN
    2        1          3           NaN         NaN
    2        2         NaN          NaN          1
    2        3          2           NaN          2
    2        4          3           NaN         NaN
    3        1          3            2          NaN
    3        2         NaN          NaN          1
    3        3         NaN          NaN          1
```

I've been trying to create a new column with the total number of kids that every member has, which implies relating the values of columns 3 and 4 with the second one, always for the same household.

I've tried achieving this with a for loop starting only with 'Lives_with_m' and I realized its quite slow. Most importantly, I couldn't get the expected results.

```
for p in set(d['Household']):
    u = d['Member']
    v = d['Lives_with_m']
    if  bool(set(u) & set(v)):
        d['New_col'] = 0
```

I'm not sure if i'm going in the right direction... Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
d = {'group': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'member': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], 'lives_with_m': [np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 3, 3, np.nan, 2, 3, 3, np.nan, np.nan], 'lives_with_f': [np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan  }
pd.DataFrame(data= d)
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: The last column in the data frame (New_col)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go, would be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'group': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'member': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], 'lives_with_m': [np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 3, 3, np.nan, 2, 3, 3, np.nan, np.nan], 'lives_with_f': [np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data= d)

value_counts = df.groupby('group')[['lives_with_m','lives_with_f']].agg({i:'value_counts' for i in ['lives_with_m','lives_with_f']}).apply(lambda x: np.nansum(x), axis=1)
value_counts.name = 'new'

df = df.merge(value_counts, how='left', left_on=['group','member'], right_index=True)
df

    group  member  lives_with_m  lives_with_f  new
0       1       1           NaN           NaN  1.0
1       1       2           NaN           NaN  1.0
2       1       3           2.0           1.0  1.0
3       1       4           NaN           NaN  1.0
4       1       5           3.0           4.0  NaN
5       2       1           3.0           NaN  NaN
6       2       2           NaN           NaN  1.0
7       2       3           2.0           NaN  2.0
8       2       4           3.0           NaN  NaN
9       3       1           3.0           2.0  NaN
10      3       2           NaN           NaN  1.0
11      3       3           NaN           NaN  1.0
```

- First, we use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to isolate `['lives_with_m','lives_with_f']` per group.
- Next, we use [`df.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) to a retrieve [`df.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) for both columns.
- Finally, we apply [`np.nansum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) to each row to end up with a `pd.Series` looking like this:

```
print(value_counts)
group     
1      2.0    1.0
       3.0    1.0
2      3.0    2.0
       2.0    1.0
3      3.0    1.0
1      1.0    1.0
       4.0    1.0
3      2.0    1.0
Name: new, dtype: float64
```

At this stage, we just need to merge the original `df` with our `series` on the  matching columns (left: `['group','member']`, right: `s.index`).